# How to use GCC to compile C code to 8088 Assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, assembly

I've been looking for a piece of information and couldn't seem to find it, maybe you guys could give me a hand. It's a simple question:

- How to use GCC to compile C code into 8088 assembly?

I'm coding a small program in 8088 assembly and would like to know how some things are done by the compiler, this would be really great.

Thanks!

Comment: The title says 8088 and the tags say 8086. Which one do you need?

Comment: I can't create tags just yet and 8086 was the only one available. Also, isn't 8086/8088 the same family? I don't think that changes anything the assembly generated code. Or am I wrong?

Comment: why don't you ask your teacher?

Comment: Apparently DJ Delorie has [a patch](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/16bit/gcc/): **This is not for the average programmer.**

Comment: First, thanks for the attention here. Second: Why is everyone telling me that? It's a weekend and I can't contact him, that's why I came to ask **you** guys. I'm sorry, David, but if I'm asking here, I don't think it matters if I could get the answer from someone else, because it's you guys that I am asking. If you know how to help me, please do, alright? Thanks again.

Comment: @WTP, what is the exact difference between 8086/8088 (besides the bus, instruction queue, etc). The tag is ok.

Comment: @pmg Thanks for the info, but can't it be done "natively" with gcc? That's what I've been told, at least. If not, then I suppose I could try that patch, but first I need to find that out. Thanks again.

Comment: @BeOliveira If it could do it natively, there would be no need for the patch.

Comment: @Neil That does make sense, yes. And I hope you understand my confusion but that's what I've been instructed by my teacher, so I really expected a possibility here. Can you think of any other way to generate 8086/8088 Assembly from a C code? Or just the patch?

Comment: @BeOliveira Yes, try and find an old DOS C compiler - maybe Turbo C.

Comment: @Neil Sh*t. What about for Linux?

Comment: @BeOliveira Linux has never run on the 8088, so you would be looking at a cross-compiler, which is what the patch pmg pointed to is (I think). Basically, you can't do it. And you haven't said why tyou think you need to do this, either. Perhaps there is some better and much easier solution, if you described your real problem.

Comment: Maybe you can download the source and compile an [old release of gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) that targeted 8086? First you have to find such a release, then compile with gcc 4.5.3 (or whatever) and hope the libraries work (of course you could download and compile the same libraries used at the time). Best of luck!

Comment: @pmg Well, it sounds like an option. Hopefully this will work, I'll give it a try. And sounds like I'll need luck too! Thank you!

Comment: @Neil Alright, here we go: I'm writing a program in 8086/8088 Assembly that will get a user's float input as a string, ex. ("3.14") and convert it to float in the IEEE 754 standards, then calculate with some other float. The thing is, my Assembler (as88) doesn't implemIent floating point numbers, so I need to send my string to an external program (The C program) that will convert this string into a float and return it to the stack or a register in a way that I can get this value from my Assembly program. I'm trying to compile my C program to see how it's done by the Assembler in 8088 asm.

Comment: @BeOliveira All you would see in the assembler output would be a call to a library function, as the 8088 doesn't have FP. You would be better advised to google for FP libraries written for the 8088/86  - not that I know of any particularly.

Comment: @Neil Well, that's kind of what I'm building in assembly. A library to support calculations with FP for the 8086/88 processors. That's why I need a C program to put in the stack or registers a FP, and use it from my Assembly program.

Comment: @BeOliveira, try to get Borland C (used to have in on some diskettes many years ago), run some emulator even java one will do: http://jpc.sourceforge.net/home_home.html and good luck

Comment: @Neil, there was the external 8087.  IIRC math emulation libraries at the times used the non implemented interrupt raised in the absence of a 8087 and then emulated the instruction.  But converting a string to a FP number is a library function since cpu aware of character sets have been out of fashion.

Comment: @AProg There certainly was, and I had one! It was required for the Lahey FORTRAN 77 compiler - this would be about 1985ish. But if you looked at the emitted code, you would just see library calls - the library calls then used the 8087 - same for emulation.

Comment: @Neil Those things were expensive then. The 8086 and even the x86 (but not x86-64 - good riddance) still have AAA, AAS etc. which are a kind of special arithmetic functions for BCD numbers, and AFAIK the x87 coprocessor even had a special BCD floating point number format. Or maybe I am confusing it with the 68881... doesn't really matter anymore ;-)

Comment: Folks, you know there's a really nice chat feature to carry on these interesting discussions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an 16 bit release of djgpp (which is based on gcc), which is said to be able to produce 8086/88 code [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/16bit/gcc/)

Comment: Well, to close this topic then, I'll accept that current versions of gcc **don't** produce 8086/88 assembly code and my only options are to use _djgpp plugin_ or _other compilers_ as many of you guys advised. Although the first to tell me about _djgpp_'s plugin was **@pmg**, I'm marking _this_ as the accepted answer since I _can't_ mark his. Thanks a lot to everyone who helped me with this! Have a great day everyone!

Answer (score 2):

GCC allows one specify the target machine architecture using -mtune=cpu-arch but it does not support i8088, nowadays. Supported architectures are i386 and newer architectures.

Comment: `-mtune` would only be optimization, `-march` is what you're talking about.

Comment: i wonder if finding and running an older version of gcc would be acceptable for this case

Answer (score 2):

If you can consider other compilers there is always OpenWatcom which is both open source and will produce 16-bit code.

Comment: Yes, I can consider other compilers and will definitely take a look at _OpenWatcom_. Thank you very much for the tip on this one!

Answer (score 1):

The -S flag produces assembler output, though not these days for the 8088.

```
gcc -S myfile.c
```

The output will be in myfile.s.

Comment: I know, I know, but my teacher told me I could generate 8088 assembly with gcc and that's exactly what I need. A code working with 16 bit registers only and limited to the 8086/8088 family processors.

Comment: @BeOliveira Well, obviously you should ask your teacher how to do it - that's what they are getting paid for.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's a weekend, I can't contact him and still need to do this. Plus, I'm asking you guys and hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: @BeOliveira As far as I know, the standard GCC distribution cannot generate 8088 code. There is certainly nothing in the GCC manual that matches "8088" when it is searched.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, I realized that too, but was still hoping there would be a way to do this...

Comment: I suspect your instructor wants 80386 assembly and doesn't understand that 8088 is not the same thing.... Lots of CS instructors are incompetent.

Comment: @R.. I'm not sure that's the case, since we're working on a program written for 8086/8088 processors and he told me I could do this to see how a C program would be compiled to those processors, instead of the x86 32 bit ones that gcc compiles to these days. He's actually a great teacher, that's why I was confused when you guys told me it's not possible natively.

Comment: Well you definitely could use a C compiler to check that, but gcc is not oriented towards 16bit development and difficult to make work on 16bit machines, if even possible. TurboC or something like that would probably be a better choice.